# React Router. dispatcher is null

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When I add routing with React Router to my React app, it throws error and shows warning:

Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

and

Uncaught TypeError: dispatcher is null

This is my Layout:

index.js:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js:

```
import Layout from "./components/Layout/Layout";

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Layout />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Layout.js:

```
import { Route, Routes, Outlet } from "react-router";
import Header from "./Header/Header";

function Layout(){
    return(
        <div id="layout">
            <Header />
            
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<b>Home page</b>} />
                <Route path="trade" element={<b>Trade page</b>} />
                <Route path="/forum" element={<b>Forum page</b>} />
                <Route path="/about" element={<b>About page</b>} />
            </Routes>

        </div>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "theory_workaround",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any overt issues in the code you've shared, and I can't reproduce any issues with it in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dispatcher-is-null-iljs9w). I suspect the issue is outside this code. Can you provide a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] and your package.json file?

Comment: @DrewReese. I have added package.json content to my answer. I think, this probably could be an outdated version of some npm package (like react-dom or something like this...)?

Comment: I just bumped all the dependencies in the codesandbox I linked to the same versions as specified in your package.json file and still don't see an issue. Can you fork my sandbox and then add more of your real code to see if something else is breaking it?

Comment: Ok, I will add code to your sandbox, but in the evening, because I'm not able to dump code right now. Ok?

Comment: And one more question: Where are you from? Cause I'm from Ukraine and don't know your timezone

Comment: I was facing this issue with React 18.0.0. As soon as I upgraded to v18.0.2 this error was gone.

Comment: I'm UTC-7. Just fork and update a sandbox when you can and ping me here in a comment and I'll check when available.

Answer (score 5):

this happen to me today,
I solve it by reinstall material ui since it was the one cause the issue whenever am using MUI component
at firm I install mui with this command

`npm install mui`

Then i had to unistall it with this command

`npm uninstall mui`

the i install using the [get started](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/#default-installation) from mui docs with this command

`npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled`

EDIT:
and another thing i was also getting the error when am using MUI icons so i actually fix it my install mui icons with the following command

`npm install @mui/icons-material`

Also for your case:
You may have a mismatch version between React and React DOM installed
you may use this command to download the lasted of both react and react DOM

`npm install react@latest react-dom@latest`

also update your `react-router-dom` to the lastest version

`npm install react-router-dom@latest`

Thanks hope it will help someone

Answer (score 0):

This helped for me, Insert

```
import { Route, Routes, Outlet } from "react-router";
```

after

```
import Header from "./Header/Header";
```

I therefore should look like this

```
import Header from "./Header/Header";
import { Route, Routes, Outlet } from "react-router";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mismatching versions of react and the render dependencies like React Router.
This mostly the issue when people tend to be running a legacy code and installing new versions of dependencies. I would suggest and this is not and expert advice, but i strongly believe it should solve it

```
npm update
```

or
delete your node modules and package-lock.json and run

```
npm install
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Use react-router-dom not react-router.
2. Have you even imported BrowserRouter from react-router (react-router-dom should be) in index.js?

Comment: Sure I have imported it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Vivaan Kumar! Please use the comments to ask for clarification. Answers should contain the solution to the problem at hand.