# dispatcher is null error react and material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend

Issue:
Mui components not working on my device.

Expected:
Compile
Imported components from mui should display on my screen when i run my react app

My code:

```
//App.js
import ButtonAppBar from './mainPage/AppBar';

function App() {
    return (
      <>
        <ButtonAppBar />
      </>
    );
}

export default App; 


//AppBar.js


import * as React from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

export default function ButtonAppBar() {
  return (
    <>
        <Button variant="outlined">Outlined</Button>
        <Button variant="outlined">Outlined</Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Result:
Compiles (no errors, visual studio code),
Imported components do not render, get an empty white screen or dispatcher is null error.

Comment: Do you use react-router on it? I think it is related to react-router package according to I investigated. You can remove mui to make sure what is the reason for the error. If the error is not regarding mui package, you can look at [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72995325/react-router-dispatcher-is-null)

Comment: It works without mui, i just wrote hello world and it shows up on the screen. However when I import mui components i get this error. And no I have not messed around with any of the .json files/dependencies etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, fixed it myself.
What I did wrong: I imported the dependencies/packages through the cmd line, assuming it would work like python, where if you import it there it will be saves on your computer forever.
How I fixed it:
I had to open the file that holds all the json files/src folder etc. I /cd to that directory then imported the packages there, then I stopped getting these errors.